# 2.8x - Recovering removed properties from 2.7x .blend files

Tags: python, scripting, blend-files, conversion

I'm converting an add-on from Blender 2.79 to 2.8x (currently using 2.83.4), and unfortunately it relied on some properties tied to the **Blender Internal** render engine which were removed in 2.8. I've not had any problems recreating these for 2.8x, but I'm trying to find an a simple way to handle old .blend files which were built on 2.79.

Namely, I'm trying to recover the `Material.texture_slots` property which no longer exists in 2.8. I've tried searching for it after opening a legacy .blend file, and I've tried loading/linking a file in a script using `bpy.data.libraries.load`. But it appears that any properties without a 2.8x equivalent are always discarded once the file is loaded.

Is there any way to read these removed properties without requiring a user to have 2.79 installed? I'm trying to avoid a scenario where they need to pull down a new release of the 2.79 add-on, load their blend file(s) in 2.79, then run a script to copy the relevant BI properties over to the new custom properties I created for 2.8x, then save a copy of the blend file.